# interesting error: new form has black line across it, how do I get rid of it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I was creating a new form and my IDE crashed, or it was having problems, and now every time I create a new form it has a black line across it.  The black line is not something I was adding, it appears to be the black line from the top of the form getting painted in the wrong place.  The interesting thing is that every time I reload the form the line moves up until after the 5th load it disappears.  How do I stop this happening?  I have tried build, rebuild, clean solution (restart visual studio) but it is still there, it isn't consistent either which also annoying, any ideas?

[image: screenshot of form with black line through it]

Comment: Sounds like you borked your designer.

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen.

Comment: Have you tried in a new solution?

Comment: Aren, yep sounds like it.  Hans, screencapped.  jms, no, but I will give it a go but I was wondering if I could do anything else first.

Answer (score 1):

The way the line appears overtop of the window (it goes *over* the border) makes it look like it's probably outside of the Designer-generated code.

Some exploratory coding:

1. Make a backup!
2. Try commenting out as much code-behind as possible.  Test if it recurs with *only* the designer-generated code.

   - if it doesn't, then slowly uncomment your code-behind.  The highest-risk code is anything that either directly manipulates the Graphics system.
   - if it does, then try commenting out different control declarations until it goes away (you'll be tweaking generated code, so this is where a good backup is critical)

To help test, can you comment out any code-behind so that it's *only* the Designer-generated code and see if it still occurs?

Comment: I did try this but nothing appears to correspond to the line.

Answer (score 0):

If every time you go in design mode the line moves up it should be in the code behind in the Designer-generated code as mentioned above, If not try to look in Form_Initialize, If not check if you use a user-control(That is not one of vs standard, maybe one you wrote yourself)
and do the same checks there (Could even be in the constructor of the user-control).

Comment: Also try reset vs settings:
Run "devenv.exe /resetsettings"

Comment: The line does not show in the designer, only when the app is run.